# Replace everything but digits

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s = Promo 77
```

I am trying to get the output "77".

The following is the regex I am using:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^[0-9]','',s)
'Promo 77'
```

What should the correct statement be here?

Comment: Have you tried `r'\d+'` for the regex?

Comment: `^[0-9]` should be `[^0-9]` in your regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'Promo 77'
>>> "".join(i for i in s if i.isdigit())
'77'
```

Comment: It's better to pass a list comprehension than a generator expression to `str.join`; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9060653/3001761

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to move the `^`. `r'^[0-9]'` matches the beginning of the string, followed by a digit (which does not appear in your string). You want `r'[^0-9]'`, which matches any character that is not a digit, or `r'\D'`, which matches exactly the same set of characters.

Comment: You can also replace 0-9 with \d

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, `\D` is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "Promo 77"
print re.findall("\d+",s)
['77']
print s.split()[-1]
77
re.sub(r'\D', "", s)
77
re.sub(r"[^\d+]","",s)
77
```